# How to move a LAMP setup to a new Ubuntu server?

Tags: server, lamp

I have an old Ubuntu LAMP server. I'd like to move the webpage over to a newer Ubuntu server and I'm wondering what the easiest way to backup and restore the webpage would be? Or just the easiest way to transfer the settings to a new server.

The first idea that came to my mind was just to set up a new LAMP server and then recreate the database, import the data,... but there must be a better way, right? :)

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Is it running LAMPP or did you install apache, php and mysql separately?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Your new server might not have the same hardware.
- So install LAMPP server on the new system.
- Shutdown the mysql service.

  `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`
- Then copy /var/lib/mysql from the old system over to the new system.
- Then copy /var/www from the old system to the new system.
- Start up mysql again.

  `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

**Note:**

- Most of the time copying /var/lib/mysql from one system to another system will work.
- In anycase if that din work for you,then do **mysqldump** on the old server and run the resulting sql on the new server with **mysqlimport**.

  `mysqldump --all-databases > db_name.sql`
  `mysqlimport db_name.sql`

Comment: Thanks! I've always been trying to find where the mysql databases are in the file system.

Comment: Also, you might want to make sure the ownership is set right--it seemed to make my mysql not start when it was wrong. (Then I had to purge/reinstall all the mysql stuff after that).